# How to add condition in jquery get() or any response condition to the function

Tags: jquery, get

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: d]

I'm making an inventory application.
I am passing values of t1 and t2 on connection page, connection page connects to sqlserver and it runs perfectly, wanting to add condition to response of get().

I have used rows_affected and did echo test.
Want to add condition to  if(response==="test") or maybe response.contains("test")
But nothing is working out

Comment: What do you get on console log from your response?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, use the code formatting tools instead.  Can you give an example of what you tried, and the output that you get in console?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: you could start your response like 1:content, 2:content etc. and then in your success handler if(response.substring(0, 2) == '1 or 2')

Comment: or more clean would be working with http header status codes but it seems like your application is not suited for that

Comment: @Rakowu I have added console-log screenshot and screenshot of output. Actually I'm getting values of a=ITEMNUMBER and b=location code. I just used function pollserverfornewmail to refresh the data time to time. I have 4 php files. 1: input item number and location. 2: Calling 3rd php file using jquery get() function to show list. 4: connection file to display data. I just want to put some if condition in jquery,  so that if item number is exact, it should go to page 4 directly, and dosen't go to listview of 3rd php file.

Comment: @Withnail I tried to post code firstly, but couldn't. I posted code for the first time. Don't have proficiency in posting code. Will surely try to do it again.

Comment: @JohannesGrandy Can you please tell me how it works with if(response.substring(0, 2) == '1 or 2'), Couldn't work. It just goes to " another view" alert.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do exactly so here a quick and unspecific example of how you can do different things in your ajax success.

The JS:

```
jQuery.get( "target.php", function( response ) {

    if( response.substring( 0,2 ) == '1:' ) {

        jQuery( '#content' ).html( response.substring(2) );

    } else if( response.substring( 0,2 ) == '0:' ) {

        alert( 'There was an error: ' + response.substring(2) );

    } else {

        alert( 'Unexpected output' );

    }

});
```

The target.php handler that processes the call:

```
$number = rand(1, 10);

if( $something < 5 ) {

    echo "1:Your number is: $number";

} else {

    echo "0:The number $number is too big.";

}
```